# Get connection status on Socket.io client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io, and I'd like to know the status of connection to the server from the client-side.

Something like this:

```
socket.status // return true if connected, false otherwise
```

I need this information to give a visual feedback to the user if the connection has dropped or it has disconnected for any reason.

Comment: Are you using socket.io client listed: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client or simple socket.io library?

Comment: I'm using the javascript file served from Node.js, so I think it's the first one.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can check the `socket.connected` property:

```
var socket = io.connect();
console.log('check 1', socket.connected);
socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('check 2', socket.connected);
});
```

It's updated dynamically, if the connection is lost it'll be set to `false` until the client picks up the connection again. So easy to check for with `setInterval` or something like that.

Another solution would be to catch `disconnect` events and track the status yourself.

Comment: It works perfectly. I didn't find this property on the docs, so thanks for the precious info ;)

Comment: I found it by `console.log`'ing the `socket` variable ;)

Comment: In v1.0 it's now `socket.connected` not `socket.socket.connected`.

Comment: @robertklep But its returning true if my client gets soft killed but connection is disconnected from server. And false if I kill server.

Comment: Seams like now in v1.0 version it is io.socket.isConnected()

Comment: Is there anyway I can find documentation on javascript objects for libraries or do we just have to go in bind every-single-time?

Comment: how to save ourself unauthorised from connect to our socket.io connection??

Comment: @VikasBansal please create a new question for that, it's not related to this one.

Comment: can u help me bcoz i am getting some problem to check socket s connected   or not

Comment: In socket.io 2.0.2 I'm using `socket.connected` and it's behaving as expected (returning either true or false). Note it's `false` immediately after calling `io(server)` but becomes `true` almost immediately after. I'm not sure if that's a race condition, though I note there isn't a callback option to `io()` so I think it's just how it works.

Comment: @IainCollins instead of callbacks, it uses events. `io(...)` is merely telling `socket.io` to connect, but only when the `connect` event has been emitted has it actually connected.

Comment: @robertklep Sorry I just re-read your answer instead of skimming it and realised that exactly what you said.

Comment: @robertklep do you know what I describe below (my answer)?

Comment: @Qiulang not sure why `socket.connected` wouldn't be set after a reconnect, you'd expect it to be `true`.

Comment: In  'ng-socket-io'  is .socket.ioSocket.connected;

Answer (score 9):

You can check whether the connection was lost or not by using this function:-

```
var socket = io( /**connection**/ );
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
//Your Code Here
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 8):

These days, socket.on('connect', ...) is not working for me.
I use the below code to check at 1st connecting.

```
if (socket.connected)
  console.log('socket.io is connected.')
```

and use this code when reconnected.

```
socket.on('reconnect', ()=>{
  //Your Code Here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Track the state of the connection yourself. With a boolean. Set it to `false` at declaration. Use the various events (connect, disconnect, reconnect, etc.) to reassign the current boolean value. Note: Using undocumented API features (e.g., `socket.connected`), is not a good idea; the feature could get removed in a subsequent version without the removal being mentioned.

Comment: socket.connected is part of the documentation and can be referenced here: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-connected

Answer (score 2):

@robertklep's answer to check socket.connected is correct except for reconnect event, https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#event-reconnect
As the document said it is "Fired upon a successful reconnection."  but when you check `socket.connected` then it is false.

Not sure it is a bug or intentional.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl "<the server URL>/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"
```

Execute the above curl in command prompt or Postman
Output should be look like below for successfull connections

```
0{"sid":"Lbo5JLzTotvW3g2LAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}
```