# Test if socket is connected

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518153/get-connection-status-on-socket-io-client), I am trying to set a variable to see if a socket is connected.

However the question's answer doesnt seem to work.  If I console.log the socket variable I get this:
[image: Console.log of var socket]

As you can see in the image, it says `connected: true` but when I run this:

`console.log(socket.connected);` I simply get false.  The start of my code looks like this:

`var socket = io('http://test.domain.net:1234', {reconnection: false});
console.log("Connected:" + socket.connected);`

Comment: Use socket.on('connect',function(){console.log('connected')});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put a timer and then do the console due to the async nature of JavaScript.

```
var socket = io('http://test.domain.net:1234', {reconnection: false});

setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("Connected:" + socket.connected);
}, 3000);
```

`

Comment: As I commented above there's an event fired when connected socket.on('connect',function(){console.log('connected')});